# How to integrate BottomSheetBehavior with BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I tried getting a Behavior in `BottomSheetDialogFragment` so I would make it not dismissable but it throws me this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
>   android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference

What do you think it might be?
Do you have any idea or tutorial how to fix this. Or something that might teach me `BottomSheetDialogFragments` in detail.

Code:

```
public class BottomSheetExcample extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false);

    view.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    view.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from();


    return view;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.bottom_sheet, null);

    TextView txt1 = view.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    TextView txt2 = view.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

    dialog.setContentView(view);
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(500, true);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomSheetExcample b = new BottomSheetExcample();
    b.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "bse");


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove onCreateView Method

```
    public class BottomSheetExample extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_cart, null);


        dialog.setContentView(view);
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(500);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you know, how to apply custom bottom sheet behavior to ModalBottomSheet?